# Getting queryset with direct results

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Is there any way to actually get queryset by direct values of params? I'm scraping data from api and sometimes there are 3 options. Single record can have full date which is year-month-day, another one could have only year-month and another could have only year. If there is certain date in my database, then i want to get it and add to the new object, but if there is not, then i want to create it. The problem is that, when i'm getting value of let's say year 2017, then i can get values of 2017, 2017-month, and 2017-month-day. Is there any way to search in database so it can act that if param have no value, then it's null?

My model here:

```
class Date(models.Model):
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    month = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(12),
            MinValueValidator(1)])
    day = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(31),
            MinValueValidator(1)])
```

Comment: We will need some more details in order to help you. Is there another model involved? Is there a reason you made a `Date` model rather than just using `DateField`? You might want to look at the `__year`, `__month`, and `__day` suffixes you can use with `filter()`.

Comment: I used Date model, because as far as i know there is no way to actually create only partial datefield, so i'm creating Date objects and saving their values, and if there is no month od both month and day, then i'm just setting them to null.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So is there a `ForeignKey` declared on another model that uses this `Date` model? It will help us understand what you are doing if you show that model to illustrate.

Comment: Exactly. There is actually another object that is related with date with ForeignKey